# how to spawn and move prefabs objects frequently?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a spawner game object the spawns 2 falling prefabs randomly.

The first version of the spawner only contained the spawning system and the falling effect was a component that the prefabs had, the problem was that I wanted that as the game progresses the SpawnRatio and falling speed will get higher with synchronization so I merged the spawning and the falling systems into the spawner game object and now for some reason the objects are spawning but no falling down.

```html
public class Random_Spawn : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject cube, circle;

    public float spawnRate = 2f;
    static float fallSpeed = 2f;

    float nextSpawn = 0f;

    int whatToSpawn;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Time.time > nextSpawn)
        {
            whatToSpawn = Random.Range(1, 3);

            switch (whatToSpawn)
            {
                case 1:
                    GameObject myCube = (GameObject)Instantiate(cube, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    myCube.transform.Translate(Vector2.down * fallSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
                    myCube.transform.parent = transform;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    GameObject myCircle = (GameObject)Instantiate(circle, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    myCircle.transform.Translate(Vector2.down * fallSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
                    myCircle.transform.parent = transform;
                    break;
            }

            nextSpawn = Time.time + spawnRate;
            if (spawnRate >= 0.05)
            {
                spawnRate -= 0.04f;
                fallSpeed -= 0.04f;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the lines that set the cube and circle parents to the spawner?

Comment: Umm I'm using the fact that those prefabs are childs of the spawner to reach them later in the game so I guess it's kind of important... :/ @AlexMyers

Comment: That's fine but I'm wondering if it has any impact on the falling or not.

Comment: The objects still don't falll/move @AlexMyers

Comment: By the way, you can add a parent to your cubes and circles in the same line that you instantiate them. Simply add the parent as a 4th parameter of `Instantiate`.  e.g. `GameObject myCube = (GameObject)Instantiate(cube, transform.position, Quaternion.identity, transform);`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are only calling `Vector.Translate` once for each spawned object.  You need this to be called every frame for the movement to continue.

It would be best to attach a separate movement script to the cube and circle prefabs that calls `Vector.Translate` in their own Update() functions.

To handle the increasing fall speed you can have the new movement script reference a `fallSpeed` variable from your spawner script to adjust your `Vector.Translate` speed.

```
speed = spawner.GetComponent<Random_Spawn>().fallSpeed;
```